# SFP port in ubiquiti switch says RX Fault

Tags: hp-proliant, proxmox, sfp, ubiquiti

guys, so I recently bought an SFP cable to hook up to my server and my switch (Ubiquiti), but today, when I tried to hook everything up in the unifi controller in the port, I was connecting the SFP, I got an error saying RX Fault.

I saw some posts saying to check the bios, and the hardware is being initialized as far as I know. After looking into the bios settings, I reset the partitions to defaults, and the rest of the settings looked like it defaulted too (First time using SFP, so I don't really know what to look for).

Controller:

[image]

Proxmox:

[image]

In proxmox, it's not detecting the connection, but after inspecting the hardware, I saw a green light blink every now, and then so I guess something is being detected, and in proxmox, it detects the hardware/ports.

eno1 and eno2 are from the SFP controller hardware.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne try manual mode for SFP in Ubiquiti and set the speed to your cards manufacturer speed capability. For me fixed the issue but the error still appears

Comment: I did.  I have noticed that on shutdown, it stays active, but on startup of the Qnap, it goes offline.  I need to remove the SPF Module on the Qnap and just re-insert it to get things up again (until the next restart).

Comment: I remember doing some configurations on ubuntu and adding then to before startup for the SFP network. If I manage to find what I did ill let you know.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I ended up resolving by using a SFTP cable of the ubiquiti shop.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it out.